# Why don't Hibernate 2nd level cache metrics appear under `cache_gets_total` data but well in `hibernate_second_level_cache_requests_total`?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, prometheus, ehcache, spring-micrometer

Here is the plan: Showing my Spring boot cache metrics to Prometheus with the stack Hibernate 6, Spring boot 3, Ehcache 3, Micrometer and Prometheus.

---

I have two types of cache (they share the same `ehcache.xml` file):

- Classic cache linked to a http service (users, I won't show the details)
- Hibernate 2nd level cache linked to the h2 db using `hibernate-jcache` (countries, I show the details)

---

First of all, both users and countries caches work as expected. And Prometheus shows metrics well.

However, I don't understand why the cache `com.example.testcache.entity.Country` values are not correct with `cache_gets_total` metrics but well evaluated for `hibernate_second_level_cache_requests_total`.

[Here is the Prometheus screenshot of the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgu1t.png)

Can you explain me the results in the screenshot? Is it a bad configuration? Is there a selfish implementation not sharing his metrics?

- Thank You -

Except the `application.yml` and `ehcache.xml`, I don't have extra configuration, the dependencies by themselves are enough.

---

My `ehcache.xml` works well:

```xml
<config
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

    <service>
        <jsr107:defaults enable-management="true" enable-statistics="true"/>
    </service>

    <cache alias="com.example.testcache.entity.Country">
        <expiry>
            <ttl>5</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <heap>1000</heap>
    </cache>

    <cache alias="users">
        <expiry>
            <ttl>30</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <heap>100</heap>
    </cache>

    <cache-template name="heap-cache">
        <resources>
            <heap>50</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>
    <cache alias="default-query-results-region">
        <expiry><ttl unit="minutes">60</ttl></expiry>
        <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
    </cache>
    <cache alias="default-update-timestamps-region">
        <expiry><none/></expiry>
        <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
    </cache>
</config>
```

My `application.yml`

```yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    open-in-view: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        javax:
          # ehcache configuration file for Hibernate
          cache:
            provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
            uri: ehcache.xml
            missing_cache_strategy: fail
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          use_query_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: jcache
        generate_statistics: true
  # ehcache configuration file for the other services "users" (not Hibernate)
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
```

My `pom.xml` with the required dependencies :

- `ehcache`, `hibernate-jcache`
- `micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave`, `hibernate-micrometer`, `datasource-micrometer-spring-boot`
- `micrometer-registry-prometheus`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-cache</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-cache</name>
    <description>test-cache</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-micrometer</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ttddyy.observation</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-micrometer-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And finally FYI my `com.example.testcache.entity.Country` entity using the Hibernate `@Cache` annotation:

```java
package com.example.testcache.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Data
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```